# My prefix starts with blood, My whole is the sight of blood

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

- My prefix starts with blood.
- My suffix gives you permission.
- My infix goes really fast.
- My whole is the sight of blood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Scarlet

My prefix starts with blood.

> Scar

My suffix gives you permission.

> Let

My infix goes really fast.

> Car

My whole is the sight of blood.

> Scarlet (in colour)